# Why do I get a type mismatch error when using a UDF that returns an object of type Option[Long]?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I am trying to write a User Defined Function (UDF) in Scala that handles null values.  For my example, I'm trying to return the epoch for a column if the value is not null.  I found that Option[] is used to return nulls from a udf.

Here is my UDF:

```
def to_epoch(date: Timestamp) : Option[Long] = {
    if(date != null) {
        Option.apply(date.getTime)
    } else {
        Option.empty
    }
}

val toEpoch: (Timestamp => Option[Long]) => UserDefinedFunction = udf((_: Timestamp => Option[Long]))
```

I am creating a dataframe from a file that is read as follows, and I want to add the column "dateEpoch". I don't know how to make it handle the `Option[Long]` that my udf returns:

```
spark.read
     .schema(ListeningStatsSchema.schema)
     .json(location)
     .withColumn("dateEpoch", toEpoch(col("EventTS"))
```

The error I get is:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Column
 required: java.sql.Timestamp => Option[Long]
            .withColumn("opd", toEpoch(col("event_TS")))
```

Comment: you need to use Some(date.getTime) and None in place of Option.apply option and None in place of Option.empty or Option.empty[Long], and the error you are getting because in with column you are not providing the correct function.

Comment: The function toEpoch takes a function Timestamp => Option[Long] and you are providing column, you should pass a function there which takes Timestamp and return Option[Long]

Comment: Title of the question may well need amending @Oli

Answer (score 1):

The error you get means that the function you defined expects a `Timestamp` (cf the type provided by the REPL). Yet you are providing a `Column`, hence the error. The `Column` type is the main type you manipulate with Spark SQL. You can work with it with either predefined functions and operators (columns can be added with + for instance), or UDFs, but not with regular scala functions.

To fix your code, you need to transform your function to a spark UDF using the `udf` function. You can do it like this:

```scala
val to_epoch_udf = udf(to_epoch _)

// And we can try it:
spark.range(1).select(to_epoch_udf(current_timestamp)).show
```

which gives:

```
+------------------------+
|UDF(current_timestamp())|
+------------------------+
|1599492185730           |
+------------------------+
```